# jasypt-spring-boot-starter: password is not ascii

Tags: spring-boot, jasypt

I started to use Jasypt in spring-boot with the maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.ulisesbocchio</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasypt-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

My spring-boot starter class has these annotations:

```
@EnableEncryptableProperties
@PropertySource(name="EncryptedProperties", value = "classpath:application.properties")
```

I encrypted my password like this:

```
java -cp jasypt-1.9.4.jar org.jasypt.intf.cli.JasyptPBEStringEncryptionCLI input=password
password=mySecret algorithm=PBEWithMD5AndDES
```

and added the property like this to my application.properties:

```
server.ssl.key-store-password: ENC(jasyptEncString)
```

At start I have this command line argument:

```
--jasypt.encryptor.password=mySecret
```

But it is failing with:

*Failed to bind properties under 'server.ssl.key-store-password' to java.lang.String:
Reason: Password is not ASCII*

The password I checked, it contains only ASCII characters.

If I add this argument (which is actually the default): `--jasypt.encryptor.algorithm=PBEWithMD5AndDES`

I'm getting:

*SecretKeyFactory not available*

The very same configuration and code is working fine on a Windows machine, but not on a RHEL Linux.

Comment: Hi I am facing the same issue where my server.ssl.key-store-password: ENC(jasyptEncString) is defined in application.yml file but getting Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect  error .

Comment: what solution you used ?

Answer (score 0):

Must have Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) installed. Please check if you have that in linux.

Comment: JCE is installed, was also one of my first guesses.